# How to shuffle a list i agda?

Tags: agda, agda-stdlib

I would like to randomly shuffle a list in agda.

I thought about taking random n elements from the beginning and adding them to the end, but I couldn't get the random part to work from this approach.

Is this possible with pattern matching or do I really have to figure out random number generation?

Current state:

```
shuffle : {A : Set} -> List A -> List A
shuffle [] = []
shuffle (x ∷ []) = x ∷ []
shuffle (x ∷ x₁ ∷ xs) = ?
```

Comment: The standard library contains [a simple PRNG for ℕ](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.Nat.PseudoRandom.LCG.html), so you could use that to iteratively index into your list.

Answer (score 1):

I think the straightforward way to implement [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) is to use a monadic effect for generating random numbers:

```
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Fin
open import Data.Vec

variable
  A : Set _

open import Data.Product hiding (swap)

swap : ∀ {n} → Fin (suc n) → Vec A (suc n) → (A × Vec A n)
swap         zero    (x₀ ∷ xs) = x₀ , xs
swap {A = A} (suc i) (x₀ ∷ xs) = go i xs
  where
    go : ∀ {n} → Fin n → Vec A n → A × Vec A n
    go zero    (x ∷ xs) = x , x₀ ∷ xs
    go (suc i) (x ∷ xs) with go i xs
    ... | (x′ , xs′) = x′ , x ∷ xs′

open import Category.Monad

module Shuffle {M} (Mon : RawMonad M) (randomFin : ∀ {n} → M (Fin (suc n))) where
  open RawMonad Mon

  shuffle : ∀ {n} → Vec A n → M (Vec A n)
  shuffle [] = pure []
  shuffle {n = suc n} xs@(_ ∷ _) = do
    k ← randomFin
    let (x′ , xs′) = swap k xs
    xs″ ← shuffle xs′
    pure (x′ ∷ xs″)
```

So how do we produce random `Fin n`s? @mudri's comment points us to [`Data.Nat.PseudoRandom.LCG`](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.Nat.PseudoRandom.LCG.html) which suggests using [`step`](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.Nat.PseudoRandom.LCG.html#761) with a state of type `ℕ`, and using simple remainder by `n` to produce a `Fin n`:

```
module ShuffleState (step : ℕ → ℕ) where
  open import Category.Monad.State
  open RawMonadState (StateMonadState ℕ)

  randomℕ : State ℕ ℕ
  randomℕ = modify step ⊛> get

  open import Data.Nat.DivMod

  randomFin : ∀ {n} → State ℕ (Fin (suc n))
  randomFin = (_mod _) <$> randomℕ

  open Shuffle monad randomFin public
```

Example usage:

```
module _ where
  open import Data.Nat.PseudoRandom.LCG
  open ShuffleState (step glibc)

  test : Vec (Fin 10) 10
  test = proj₁ (shuffle (allFin 10) 0)
```

Note that this doesn't prove that the output is indeed a permutation of the input. If you need that, I think it's easier to change `shuffle` and `swap` to produce a permutation witness (e.g. like [this](https://github.com/bobatkey/sorting-types/blob/master/agda/Linear.agda#L79-L83)) instead of operating on the input vector directly and proving it externally.

**Edited to add**:
In Idris 2 at least, we can prove that `shuffle` is linear in the shuffled vector by just using linear types where they matter:

```
import Data.Vect
import Data.Fin

swap : Fin (S n) -> (1 xs : Vect (S n) a) -> Vect (S n) a
swap FZ     (x0 :: xs) = (x0 :: xs)
swap (FS i) (x0 :: xs) = go i xs
  where
    go : Fin k -> Vect k a -> Vect (S k) a
    go FZ     (x :: xs) = x :: x0 :: xs
    go (FS i) (x :: xs) =
      let (x' :: xs') = go i xs in
      x' :: x :: xs'

shuffle: Monad m => (randomFin : {k : _} -> m (Fin (S k))) => {n : _} -> (1 xs : Vect n a) -> m (Vect n a)
shuffle [] = pure []
shuffle (x::xs) = do
  k <- randomFin
  let (x' :: xs') = swap k (x :: xs)
  xs'' <- shuffle xs'
  pure (x' :: xs'')
```

Note the type of `xs` in the signature of `shuffle`. I think parametricity + linearity together here should be sufficiently convincing that `shuffle` indeed shuffles its input.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the detailed answer, this goes a lot deeper than i thought.